# Basis for nullspace and column sqace

Tags: linear-algebra

Why the dimension of nullspace is the # of free variable but the dimension of the column space is the # of pivot column ?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What don't you understand?

Comment: This question is too broad for this site, even ignoring the fact that it's really two questions in one. These questions are standard theory, and answers can be found in most linear algebra textbooks. It's not really feasible to answer these questions here, in little text boxes, without some idea of the theory that you're familiar with.